# Combinatorics or Linear Algebra for Computer Science/Applied Mathematics Degree?

Tags: mathematics, computer-science, coursework

I'm looking to graduate in the upcoming Spring with a BS in Computer Science and Applied Mathematics, and was curious on which of the two courses would be most applicable moving forward. I'm only able to take one of either "Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory" or "Combinatorics and Graph Theory" next semester, given that I'll be entering the field of Software Engineering following graduation.

Certainly, one class won't make or break one's education in the grand scheme of things, but I wanted to know which would serve best moving forward in engineering, or at the least to round out an applied mathematics degree.

Either way, thanks for your consideration with this dilemma of mine.

Comment: Did you take any other courses on linear algebra or discrete math? I don't see how you would learn algorithms without some basic graph theory (although it is not that difficult to pick up by yourself).

Comment: In terms of previous math courses, I've taken a basic vectors and matrices class, vector calculus (Calculus III), discrete mathematics, and differential equations. Computer Science courses get into various structures as necessary, I've worked more with graphs just by nature of the general problems we solve in those classes (traversal of graphs via adjacency matrices)

Comment: ok - given your answer I agree with Dave Clarke.

Comment: I suspect this question is off-topic here. (Please see http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for "Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory" as you'll need that if you ever need to do any machine learning or computer graphics, both of which are increasingly common "tools" for modern software systems.

Learning a bit about graphs too wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I didn't find this book. Would you please tell its authors or publications. Thank you.